# WSO2 Error occurred while modifying user entry

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We use WSO2 identity, and we are trying to add a new user to AD as secondary store by WSO2 the user

We created successfully, but also got an error message after user created as shown below:

[image]]

in log file we catch this error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-05 21:59:13,215] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=user022)) in SearchBase:  
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-05 21:59:13,218] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Name in space for user022 is CN=user022,CN=Users,DC=DEVDC,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-05 21:59:13,229] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for role: Domain Users 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-05 21:59:13,230] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Using search filter: (&(objectcategory=group)(cn=Domain Users)) 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-05 21:59:13,235] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching in CN=Users,DC=devdc,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-05 21:59:13,237] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Is role: Domain Users exist: true 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-05 21:59:13,240] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Modifying role: CN=Domain Users with type: 1 user: CN=user022,CN=Users,DC=DEVDC,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa in search base: CN=Users,DC=devdc,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-05 21:59:13,249] DEBUG **{org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Error occurred while modifying user entry: CN=user022,CN=Users,DC=DEVDC,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa in LDAP role: CN=Domain Users 
javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: [LDAP: error code 68 - 00000528: UpdErr: DSID-031A11E2, problem 6005 (ENTRY_EXISTS), data 0
 ]; remaining name 'CN=Domain Users'**
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3149)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3100)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2891)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1408)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_modifyAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:257)
```

Comment: Did you try to change the name to an existing value?

Comment: No, the message appear ,when we try to save new user with new name not during modifying existing name

Comment: Do you add any roles to the user when you add the user?

Comment: yes, i add roles to user from message up you can see that i added user to devdc/Domain Users

Comment: Is it working if you just add the user without adding roles?

Comment: no sir still give the same message